# Table formatting with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to format the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}  % package for tablenotes
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx} % booktabs is used for horizontal lines (\toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule)
\usepackage{array} % used together with tabularx
\usepackage{mathcomp} % for symbols

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\linespread{1}\selectfont Fetal and neonatal complications in type 1 diabetic pregnancies and the general obstetric population}

\footnotesize
\linespread{1}\selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcXXX}
 &  \multicolumn{2}{X}{Proportions (\% if not indicated otherwise)} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{OR (95\% Cl) for group differences} \tabularnewline
\cline{2-5} 
Outcome variable & Type 1 diabetes & Control & Crude & Adjusted \tabularnewline
\toprule
Stillbirth  & 1.5 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline
Fetal distress & 14 & 12.3 & g & h\tabularnewline
Perinatal mortality (\textperthousand) & 20 & j & k & l\tabularnewline
Neonatal mortality, 0--7 days (\textperthousand) & 5.1 & n & o & p\tabularnewline 
Neonatal mortality, 0--28 days (\textperthousand)  & 7.0 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
Birth \textless37 weeks gestational age  & 21 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
Birth \textless37 weeks gestational age  & 2.3 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
LGA  & 31 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline
SGA  & 2.3 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
Major malformations  & 4.7 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
Apgar score \textless7 at 5 min  & 3.1 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
Apgar score \textless4 at 5 min  & 0.80 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
Erb palsy*  & 2.1 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
Respiratory distress syndrome  & 1.0 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline 
Respiratory disorders  & 9.5 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40)) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\label{tab:fetal}
\begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item{\linespread{1}\selectfont Data are proportions or OR (95\% Cl). Adjusted OR, OR adjusted for group differences in maternal age, BMI, parity, chronic hypertensive disorder, smoking habits, and ethnicity. *Vaginal deliveries only.}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, this is the output:

[image]

And this is what I would like to get:

[image]

Do you know how to properly format this table?

Comment: Comparing your two screenshots, it looks like the entries in the final three columns are quite different. Is there any significance to this discrepancy?

Comment: No, I just have to add the final values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- increase the widths of the 2-column headers
- adjust the relative widths of the `X`-type columns so that no line wrapping is required in the final two columns. In the code below, observe that the relative widths of the four `L` columns sums to `4` (the number of such columns), and that the relative widths of the two `C` columns also sums to `4`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, vmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx,mathcomp}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\linespread{1}\selectfont
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Fetal and neonatal complications in type 1 diabetic 
pregnancies and the general obstetric population}
\label{tab:fetal}

\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l
                           >{\hsize=1.15\hsize}L
                           >{\hsize=0.55\hsize}L
                      *{2}{>{\hsize=1.15\hsize}L} @{}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=1.7\hsize}C}{Proportions (\% if not indicated otherwise)} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2.3\hsize}C}{OR (95\% CI) for group differences} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
Outcome variable & Type 1 \mbox{diabetes} & Control & Crude & Adjusted \\
\midrule
Stillbirth & 1.5 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Fetal distress & 14 & 12.3 & g & h\\
Perinatal mortality (\textperthousand) & 20 & j & k & l\\
Neonatal mortality, 0--7 days (\textperthousand) & 5.1 & n & o & p\\
Neonatal mortality, 0--28 days (\textperthousand)  & 7.0 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Birth \textless{} 37 weeks gestational age  & 21 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Birth \textless{} 37 weeks gestational age  & 2.3 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
LGA  & 31 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
SGA  & 2.3 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Major malformations  & 4.7 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Apgar score \textless{} 7 at 5 min  & 3.1 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Apgar score \textless{} 4 at 5 min  & 0.80 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Erb palsy*  & 2.1 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Respiratory distress syndrome  & 1.0 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Respiratory disorders  & 9.5 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item{Data are proportions or OR (95\% CI). Adjusted OR, OR adjusted for group differences in maternal age, BMI, parity, chronic hypertensive disorder, smoking habits, and ethnicity. *Vaginal deliveries only.}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: I assume the additional objective of aligning numbers on their (implicit or explicit) decimal markers pertains to columns 2 and 3 of the table. As the following table shows, it's possible to use the `S` column type for the numbers and to use (modified) `C` columns for the two headers cells -- "Type 1 diabetes" and "Control", respectively. Note, incidentally, that the cell entries "j" and "n" need to be encased in curly braces to keep siunitx from (mis)interpreting what these symbols may mean.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, vmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,mathcomp,siunitx
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\linespread{1}\selectfont
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Fetal and neonatal complications in type 1 diabetic 
pregnancies and the general obstetric population}
\label{tab:fetal}

\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l
                      *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]}               
                      *{2}{>{\hsize=1.15\hsize}L} @{}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=1.7\hsize}C}{Proportions (\% if not indicated otherwise)} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2.3\hsize}C}{OR (95\% CI) for group differences} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
Outcome variable 
& \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=1.15\hsize}C}{Type 1 diabetes} 
& \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=0.55\hsize}C}{Control}
& Crude & Adjusted \\
\midrule
Stillbirth & 1.5 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Fetal distress & 14 & 12.3 & g & h\\
Perinatal mortality (\textperthousand) & 20 & {j} & k & l\\
Neonatal mortality, 0--7 days (\textperthousand) & 5.1 & {n} & o & p\\
Neonatal mortality, 0--28 days (\textperthousand)  & 7.0 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Birth \textless{} 37 weeks gestational age  & 21 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Birth \textless{} 37 weeks gestational age  & 2.3 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
LGA  & 31 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
SGA  & 2.3 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Major malformations  & 4.7 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Apgar score \textless{} 7 at 5 min  & 3.1 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Apgar score \textless{} 4 at 5 min  & 0.80 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Erb palsy*  & 2.1 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Respiratory distress syndrome  & 1.0 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
Respiratory disorders  & 9.5 & 0.3 & 4.04 (3.02--5.40) & 3.34 (2.46--4.55)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item{Data are proportions or OR (95\% CI). Adjusted OR, OR adjusted for group differences in maternal age, BMI, parity, chronic hypertensive disorder, smoking habits, and ethnicity. *Vaginal deliveries only.}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico. What is the significance of the command @{}? (I'm a novice)

Comment: @Luigi - It removes the whitespace that would otherwise be inserted to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column. Observe that there's no such whitespace in the second screenshot you posted. That's why I inserted the `@{}` particles.

Comment: @MicoDo you know how to turn the L column types you provided into S column types (with the siunitx package), in order to properly align the numbers?

Comment: @Luigi - Basically, the answer is "yes". :-) I've posted an addendum to address your follow-up question in more detail.

Comment: @Mico- How did you manage to put some space above and below the second line (the one of outcome variable, type 1 diabetes, control, crude, adjusted)?

Comment: @luigi - The `\cmidrule` and `\midrule` macros automatically add a bit of vertical whitespace. :-)